# how to make 2 = .01 and .01 = 2?

Tags: c++, integer

Okay so the title may not make the most sense but I will explain it better here.. what i'm trying to do is take the value of 2 and make it equal to .01 and make .01 = 2, well I tried to hardcode it like this

```
 if (Value = 2)
    Value = 0;
else if (Value = 1.99)
    Value = .01;
else if (Value = 1.98)
    Value = .02;
else if (Value = 1.97)
    Value = .03;
else if (Value = 1.96)
    Value = .04;
else if (Value = 1.95)
    Value = .05;
```

(I did that all the way down to 0... however it didn't function properly

I also tried to get the inverse of the value like so..

```
Value = 1 / Value;
```

Now if the value was 2 it would return it to .5 and if the value was 1 it would set it to 1.. I knew this wouldn't work when I tried I just didn't know what to do... If anyone could lead me in the right direction that would be cool.. (also I think this thread is a little bit better than my past threads seeing how I explained it :^) )

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is equality comparison. `if (Value = 2)` doesn't do what you likely think it does.

Comment: You wrote 200 if-else-if statements?! That's a sure sign there must be an easier way to do it.  Like in this case, how about `Value = 2 - Value;`?

Comment: also, you probably don't want to do `==` with floats, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: there are so many problems with your code. Read all the compiler warnings first. There would be a lot of warnings about variable assignment in the `if` block. And you can't compare floating-point values simply like that unless you really know what you're doing

Answer (score 3):

You're using the assignment operator "`=`". This assigns a value to a variable (such as `x = 10`). Inside your if-check clause, you want to compare both variables equality with the compare-equality operator, "`==`".

```
if (Value == 2.f) // checks if Value is equal to 2
    Value = 0.f; // sets Value equal to 0
else if (Value == 1.99f)
    Value = .01f;
else if (Value == 1.98f)
    Value = .02f;
else if (Value == 1.97f)
    Value = .03f;
else if (Value == 1.96f)
    Value = .04f;
else if (Value == 1.95f)
    Value = .05f;
```

An alternative yet complete solution to your problem:

```
if (Value <= 2.f && Value >= 0.f) // checks if Value is between or is 2 or 0
    Value = 2.f - Value; // sets !version of Value to Value
```

`Value = 1 / Value;` wouldn't work because you're trying to get the !version of Value, not the inversion of Value.

Remember to do `f` after a float check so you don't run into weird faulty comparison problems.

Comment: That `f` doesn’t avoid “weird faulty comparison problems”. It only changes the type of the constant from `double` to `float`. If floating-point comparisons seem weird and faulty, that’s the result of not understanding how they work and where the data comes from.